# Sync Between Year and Month for Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

Goal:
Sync with two dropdownlist that is for year and month in asp.net mvc 4.

Problem:
These two dropdownlist are separated and I wonder how to sync them?

Info:
*Today, year and month are located inside of Viewbag.
*It is important that the list must be inside of ViewBag, if possible.
*Please remember that if you change the year, the dropdownlist for month also will be changing.
*The list of the year starts with the highest value. THe bottom of the list begins with the oldest year.

This the table with available year and month:

```
--------------
Year    Month
--------------
2000    10
2000    12
2001    1
2001    2
2001    3
2001    4

etc...
```

---

```
string selectedmonth = 1; 
string selectedyear = 2000;



monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = "2000" == selectedyear ? true : false, Text = "2000", Value = "2000" });
monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = "2001" == selectedyear ? true : false, Text = "2001", Value = "2001" });



monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = "1" == selectedmonth ? true : false, Text = "January", Value = "1" });
monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = "2" == selectedmonth ? true : false, Text = "February", Value = "2" });
monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = "3" == selectedmonth ? true : false, Text = "March", Value = "3" });
monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = "4" == selectedmonth ? true : false, Text = "April", Value = "4" });
monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = "5" == selectedmonth ? true : false, Text = "May", Value = "5" });
monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = "6" == selectedmonth ? true : false, Text = "June", Value = "6" });
monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = "7" == selectedmonth ? true : false, Text = "July", Value = "7" });
monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = "8" == selectedmonth ? true : false, Text = "August", Value = "8" });
monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = "9" == selectedmonth ? true : false, Text = "September", Value = "9" });
monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = "10" == selectedmonth ? true : false, Text = "October", Value = "10" });
monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = "11" == selectedmonth ? true : false, Text = "November", Value = "11" });
monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = "12" == selectedmonth ? true : false, Text = "December", Value = "12" });

ViewBag.YearList = yearlist;
ViewBag.MonthList = monthlist;
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have two dropdownlist - one for Year and other for month. Whenever user select any value from year then the corresponding months in DataTable should be automatically populated in Month dropdownlist. For e.g if user select  2000 then month dropdown should have values 10 & 12. correct?

Comment: You need javascript/jquery to handle the `.change()` event of the `year` dropdownlist` and call a server method that returns the values that should be selected for the selected year. Note there is no need to set the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` if your binding to a property. And why are you making it difficult for yourself by using `ViewBag` instead of strongly binding to a view model?

Comment: And based on your confirmation of  Gagan Jaura's comment, then you can have multiple selected values for a year, so `selectedmonth` needs to be `IEnumerable<int>` (not `string`)

Comment: Stephen - "strongly binding to a view model", do you have more information about it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use javascript/jquery to handle the `.change()` event of the `SelectedYear` dropdown and update the `SelectedMonth` listbox, for example by calling a server method using ajax. You will find all this easier if you use a view model and strongly bind to your properties rather than using `ViewBag` for everything. Note that since you can have multiple months for a year, your `SelectedMonths` property needs to be an array.

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public int SelectedYear { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> SelectedMonths { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Years { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Months { get; set; }
}
```

and in the GET method, initialize and return an instance of the view model

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    SampleViewModel model = new SampleViewModel()
    {
        SelectedYear = 2001, // set default
        SelectedMonths = new List<int>{ 1, 2 }, // set default based on default year
        Years = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem(){ Value = "2000", Text = "2000" },
            new SelectListItem(){ Value = "2001", Text = "2001" }
        },
        Months = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem(){ Value = "1", Text = "January" },
            new SelectListItem(){ Value = "2", Text = "February" },
            ....
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view

```
@model SampleViewModel
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ....
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedYear, Model.Years) 
    ....
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedMonths, Model.Months)
    ....
}
```

Then add a script to handle the change event of the dropdownlist

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '@Url.Action("FetchMonths")';
    $('#SelectedYear').change(function() {
        $.getJSON(url, { selectedYear: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
            $('#SelectedMonths').val(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

which would call the following method

```
public JsonResult FetchMonths(int selectedYear)
{
    IEnumerable<int> months = db.yourTable().Where(x => x.Year == selectedYear).Select(x => x.Month);
    return Json(months, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```