# Send value from two dropdownlist to actionresult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

Goal:
When I select the dropdownlist for the month, the selected data from the dropdownlist year and month shall be transferred to the parameter of the actionresult Index without using a submit button. The data will be sent to the controller when you make a selection in the dropdownlist for month.

When data as entered to the parameter and ended to the view() and then I would like the webpage to be refreshed.

Problem:
I dont know how to do it.

Info:
*I'm using asp.net mvc 4 with VS2013.
*Please rememeber that I must have "ViewBag.YearList = Yearlist;" and ViewBag.MonthList = monthlist;" because it is used in production phase.
*https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hg9CKn
*You would say that the link of the dropdownlist is similiar as `@Html.ActionLink("LINK","Index", "Home", new {@year = *here*, @year = *here*})`    *When you click on dropdownlist for month, I would like the webpage index to be refreshed from scratch before presenting the information in cshtml if possible.

Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(string year, string month)
        {

            if (year == null)
            {
                year = "2000";
            }

            if (month == null)
            {
                month = "1";
            }

            List<SelectListItem> Yearlist = GetYear(year);

            List<SelectListItem> monthlist = GetMonth(month);

            ViewBag.YearList = Yearlist;
            ViewBag.MonthList = monthlist;          


            return View();
        }


        private List<SelectListItem> GetYear(string selectedyear)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> Yearlist = new List<SelectListItem>();

            Yearlist.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Selected = "2000" == selectedyear ? true : false,
                Text = "2000",
                Value = "2000"
            });

            Yearlist.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Selected = "2001" == selectedyear ? true : false,
                Text = "2001",
                Value = "2001"
            });

            return Yearlist;

        }



        private List<SelectListItem> GetMonth(string selectedmonth)
        {

            List<SelectListItem> monthlist = new List<SelectListItem>();


            monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Selected = "0" == selectedmonth ? true : false,
                Text = "All months",
                Value = "0"
            });

            monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Selected = "1" == selectedmonth ? true : false,
                Text = "Jan",
                Value = "1"
            });

            monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Selected = "2" == selectedmonth ? true : false,
                Text = "Feb",
                Value = "2"
            });


            monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Selected = "3" == selectedmonth ? true : false,
                Text = "Mars",
                Value = "3"
            });


            monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Selected = "4" == selectedmonth ? true : false,
                Text = "April",
                Value = "4"
            });

            monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Selected = "5" == selectedmonth ? true : false,
                Text = "Maj",
                Value = "5"
            });

            monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Selected = "6" == selectedmonth ? true : false,
                Text = "June",
                Value = "6"
            });

            monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Selected = "7" == selectedmonth ? true : false,
                Text = "July",
                Value = "7"
            });

            monthlist.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Selected = "8" == selectedmonth ? true : false,
                Text = "August",
                Value = "8"
            });

            return monthlist;
        }               



    }
}


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>

            @Html.DropDownList("Year", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.YearList, new { id = "selectedyear" })

            @Html.DropDownList("Month", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.MonthList, new { id = "selectedmonth" })

    </body>
</html>
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hg9CKn

Comment: You view does not have a form. Wrap your controls inside `@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get)) { ..... }` But I already showed you how to this in my answer to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171179/sync-between-year-and-month-for-dropdownlist)

Comment: I have updated my message above.

Comment: Then you need javascript/jquery to handle the `.change()` event of the dropdownlist and send the values using ajax.

Comment: Possible that you can create a sample?

Comment: My previous answer showed how to do this (In that case it passed the value of the first dropdown to the `FetchMonths()` method). Just adapt it to call a different method and pass both values. But since you have ignored that answer there is no point giving you a sample.

Comment: I will review it and thank you for your current and previous help!!!

Comment: There has been some changes in the description because the currect description of the problem statement is was not very simple explained and I also have reflected based on your input. I need to add a new message. Again, thank your for your help!

Comment: Then delete this question. Others are just going to waste their time trying to add an answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your DropDownLists into a form. Please, remove HttpGet attribute from the Index method and use folowing code in the view:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#selectedyear').change(function() {
            window.frmYearMonth.submit();
        });
        $('#selectedmonth').change(function() {
            window.frmYearMonth.submit();
        });
    });
</script>



@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmYearMonth" }))
{
    ViewContext.Writer.Write(Html.DropDownList("Year", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.YearList, new { id = "selectedyear", }));
    ViewContext.Writer.Write(Html.DropDownList("Month", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.MonthList, new { id = "selectedmonth" }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I Tried your solution but it doesn't work. I used the sourcecode into another asp.net mvc project and the code of index will not be executed after selected month from dropdownlist. Is it possible that you can provide a sample?

Comment: Did you remove `[HttpGet]` attribute from the `Index` method?

Comment: Yes, I did it...  I also have updated the message above.

Comment: There has been some changes in the description because the currect description of the problem statement is was not very simple explained and I also have reflected based on your input. I need to add a new message. Again, thank your for your help!